# Access 2013 Trying to concatenate data to a single table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to access, but I am failing at trying to complete a particular step. I have two tables:

Table 1: MAL-Topic; Using the row "Topic"

Table 2: MAL-Document; Using the row "DocumentName"

I have a foreign key in place that has all documents assigned a topic.

I want to create a query that counts all of the documents related to the topic and provide a single column feedback with the topic name and count. "Topic Name (3)"

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to call your two tables: topic_table and document_table. Of course, when you run the code, you will need to fill in the read table names in their place.

Simply join the tables using the topic id, which should be the primary key in the topic table and the foreign key in the document table. Then group by this key and the topic name.

COUNT(*) counts the number of records in your joined table for each topic ID and name.

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, COUNT(*)
FROM topic_table t
INNER JOIN document_table d ON t.id = d.topic_id
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

**Edit following comment:**

```
SELECT t.name & '(' & COUNT(*) & ')'
FROM topic t
INNER JOIN document d ON t.id = d.topic_id
GROUP BY t.name
```

Comment: I took what you said and came up wtih the following
SELECT t.ID, t.TopicName, Count(*) AS Expr1
FROM MALTopic AS t INNER JOIN MALDocument AS d ON t.id = d.TopicID
GROUP BY t.ID, t.TopicName;

Now i get three columns of data, ID, TopicName and Expr1 which is the count of documents. How do I get these three columns so I only have TopicName with the count in the topic name? TopicName (19) I am doing this in Microsoft Access.